# Diff two remote files using Perl

Tags: perl, shell, diff

I have an array of file paths:

```
@files = ('/home/.../file.txt', '/home/.../file2.txt',...);
```

I have multiple remote machines, with a similar filestructure.  How can I diff these remote files using Perl?

I thought of using Perl backticks, `ssh` and using diff, but I am having issues with `sh` (it doesn't like `diff <() <()`).

Is there a good Perl way of comparing at least two remote files?

Comment: Use `bash` if you want to use `<(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Perl Module on CPAN called Net::SSH::Perl to run remote commands.

Link: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl)

Example from the Synopsis:

```
    use Net::SSH::Perl;
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
    $ssh->login($user, $pass);
    my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

You command would look something like

```
    my $cmd = "diff /home/.../file.txt /home/.../file2.txt";
```

edit: The files are on different servers.

You can still use Net::SSH::Perl to read the files.

```
    #!/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Net::SSH::Perl;

    my $host = "First_host_name";
    my $user = "First_user_name";
    my $pass = "First_password";
    my $cmd1 = "cat /home/.../file1";

    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
    $ssh->login($user, $pass);
    my($stdout1, $stderr1, $exit1) = $ssh->cmd($cmd1);

    #now stdout1 has the contents of the first file

    $host = "Second_host_name";
    $user = "Second_user_name";
    $pass = "Second_password";
    my $cmd2 = "cat /home/.../file2";

    $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
    $ssh->login($user, $pass);
    my($stdout2, $stderr2, $exit2) = $ssh->cmd($cmd2);

    #now stdout2 has the contents of the second file

    #write the contents to local files to diff

    open(my $fh1, '>', "./temp_file1") or DIE "Failed to open file 1";
    print $fh1 $stdout1;
    close $fh1;


    open(my $fh2, '>', "./temp_file2") or DIE "Failed to open file 2";
    print $fh2 $stdout2;
    close $fh2;

    my $difference = `diff ./temp_file1 ./temp_file2`;

    print $difference . "\n";
```

I haven't tested this code, but you could do something like this. Remember to download the Perl Module Net::SSH::Perl to run remote commands.

Diff is not implemented in the Perl Core Modules, but there another called Text::Diff on CPAN so maybe that would work too. Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to diff two files from two different servers, not two files in the same server.

Comment: @jh314 see edit. Net:SSH will still work, but you'll have to use it twice to get to both machines.

Comment: Thanks!  Is creating the temp files really necessary?  Some of these files are quite large!

Comment: Creating temp files is only necessary if you want to use the diff on your machine. If you use the Text::Diff perl module, you should be able to keep them in memory and you won't need the temp files. Here's the link: http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Text-Diff-1.41/lib/Text/Diff.pm

Comment: Net::SSH and Net::SSH::Perl are two different modules.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsync` to copy the remote files to the local machine, then use `diff` to find out the differences:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh1 = Net::OpenSSH->new($host1);
$ssh1->rsync_get($file, 'master');

my $ssh2 = Net::OpenSSH->new($host2);
system('cp -R master remote');
$ssh2->rsync_get($file, 'remote');

system('diff -u master remote');
```